# SAP OLE Automation Logon() method parameters

Tags: vba, ole, saprfc

I have been using RFC SAP logon through VBA for at least five years, but I still haven't found the meaning of logon's first parameter, whilst the second one for the dialog displaying is obvious. For the first I use 0 all the time.

Could somebody explain this?

Tomek

Answer (score 0):

This is handle of parent window `HWND ParentWindow`, here is the full method signature:

```
Logon (HWND ParentWindow, Boolean Silent)
```

Here is full list of properties of `Logon` object:

[image]

You can read the full guide of SAP Automation [here](https://www.consolut.com/fileadmin/user_upload/SAP_PrintDoku/de/BCFESDE5/BCFESDE5.PDF), and the above info is on page 465.

In the guide only the second parameter is described (page 493) so probably first one is undefined or legacy, I think putting zero always will be just fine.